# Unable to access Memcached key/value in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, memcached

I run ZF1 project and ZF2 project parallel and I have implemented Memcached in both (same memcache in both). I saved key in ZF1 and can retrieve it in ZF1, but I cannot retrieve it in ZF2 and vice-versa.

ZF2 code for Memcached

```
$MemcachedResourceManager = new \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedResourceManager();
$MemcachedResourceManager->addServers('1', array('127.0.0.1', 11211));

$memcachedAdapterOptions = new \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedOptions(array(
    'resource_manager' => $MemcachedResourceManager,
    'resource_id'      => '1',
    'namespace'        => '',
    'ttl'              => 3600,
);
$cache = new \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memcached($memcachedAdapterOptions);

echo $cache->getItem('key');
die;
```

ZF1 code for Memcached

```
$frontendOptions = array(
    'caching' => true,
    'lifetime' => 0,
    'automatic_serialization' => true
);

$backendOptions = array(
    'servers' => array( array('host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 11211,) ),
    'compression' => true
);

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'Memcached', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);
$cache->save('item', 'key');
```

That's my code, where "I am not able to get key/value in ZF2".

Comment: We're going to need to see some code...

Comment: Maybe it's like the file cache - probably there is some kind of prefix/namespace for the cache entries

Answer (score 0):

In Zf1 the library 'Memcached' is the library of PHP Memcache (without 'd' !!) and the library 'Libmemcached' is the library of PHP Memcached.